# rewrite htaccess url some questions

Tags: .htaccess

I have a CMS that is generating SEFURLs almost correctly.

However, there is a menu item called `separator` that you can use as a hook for Javascript, which has no link on it.

The URL that gets created is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/separator/mycategory/mypage
```

I want to get rid of the `/separator` so that the URL looks like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/mycategory/mypage
```

Is this possible to do in the `.htaccess`? I tried a few rewrite rules and they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/separator(.*) $1
```